# "Absuelto" but not absolved

Tags: definiciones

The quote is this one : «Dios es el Absoluto en el sentido literal de esta palabra, el que está absuelto o desligado radicalmente de las cosas.»

Well, in this situation I don't think that 'absuelto' means absolved. What is the meaning of this word in this situation, then?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author here is using the etymological sense of the words *absuelto* and *absoluto*; both derive from the Latin word *absolūtus*. When he writes *absuelto o desligado radicalmente*, he is not expressing two possibilities: he means that, etymologically, *absuelto* means *desligado*.

So, if you just want to know what does *absuelto* mean in this fragment, the author himself is telling you. If you want to translate it into English, you could actually use *absolved*, since its etymological origin is the same. This reference to etymological meanings, especially for words derived from Latin or Greek, is not unusual in religious texts.

Comment: To complement your answer with @Rodrigo answer: «Both words, "absuelto" and "absoluto", are historically related. Derived from the Latin verb "solvere" which means "separate the components(...)"» http://www.wordreference.com/definition/absolve

"to make loose"/free.

Comment: OK, I've added a little explanation on the etymological link between both words.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it actually does mean *absolved*.

> Dios es el Absoluto en el sentido literal de esta palabra, el que está **absuelto** o desligado radicalmente de las cosas.
>
> God is the Absolute in the literal sense of the word, He who is **absolved** and unbound from things.

To my understanding it means that he is *absolved* (has no obligation of any kind). Since there is no authority above Him (He is the Absolute), the connotation is also that He is not absolved by a higher authority (like the verb *absolver* would imply) but rather that there where no obligations He has to respond to. So He hasn't really been freed of his obligations, rather, there were no obligations for Him and there was no one He had to respond to.

He is "absuelto y desligado": *absolved* and *unbound* (from/to) the things (*the things* meaning whatever they do in the context of this quote).

Comment: +1 thanks Diego

Answer (score 1):

Both words, "absuelto" and "absoluto", are historically related. Derived from the Latin verb "solvere" which means "*separate the components, release*". Thus:

> **Absuelto**: Which has been released from paying a fine or a payment. [*Absolved*]
>
> **Absoluto**: Something whole, which has not been divided into pieces or has parts. [*Absolute*]

The quote's writer knows this etymological relation and want to make an interesting comment, probably arcane, but it really is wrong or at least try to make believe that both words "deeply" mean the same.

No, in Spanish that someone is "absoluto" not mean it is "absuelto".

Comment: why do you say that it's wrong, if the root is really the same?

Comment: Watch this equivalent sentence: "John is the **guard** in the literal sense of the word, which stands at the door of the **ward**". "Guard" and "ward" have the same root, but not means the same.

Comment: Actually the etymological root of the words from your is not the same. Guard comes from french garder, and ward from germanic language. 

Check this http://www.wordreference.com/definition/ward

Comment: Plus 1, for the latin meaning. And thanks!